# Polynomial Bases

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering how to express $q=3-x+2x^2+5x^3$ (this is w.r.t falling power) and I need to express it, with respect to rising powers?

I am not sure how to develop the matrix such that I can multiply the matrix on the right with the coordinate vector of *'q'* thus giving me the answer.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: When you write $q=3-x+2x^2+5x^3$, this is with respect to powers of $x$, not with respect to falling powers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If the rising powers are $a=1,b=x,c=x(x+1),d=x(x+1)(x+2),$ then express each usual power in their terms and use linearity. Two are easy: $1=a,x=b$ Now note that $x^2=x(x+1)-x=c-b.$ By another calculation, $x^3=d-3c+b$.

It would then be easy to set up a matrix form of the transformation from the usual power basis to this "rising power" basis. [I've seen these called rising factorials, does rising powers mean something else?]

I got for the matrix $M$ the following, which you should check, but I tried it on $1+2x+3x^2+5x^3$ and it correctly gave the coefficients $1,4,-12,5$ for the rising factorials (powers), check via 
$1+4x-12x(x+1)+5x(x+1)(x+2)=1+2x+3x^2+5x^3.$

$M=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&-1&1\\ 0&0&1&-3\\ 0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$

ADDED:

To go directly from rising factorial coefficients to falling ones, right multiply the following matrix by the column vector of rising factorial coefficients:

$N=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&2&6\\ 0&0&1&6\\ 0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$

I got this by expressing the rising factorials in terms of the falling ones, where $R_k$ and $F_k$ denote these, e.g. $R_3=x(x+1)(x+2).$ Then $R_2=F_2+2F_1$ and $R_3=F_3+6F_2+6F_1$ which explains where the entries of $N$ come from.

Comment: Hi coffeemath ... thanks for your solution ...rising factorials and rising powers are the same. Your solution would then give me the rising factorials with respect to the usual power basis ... I have the matrix for that but I was wondering about how to express the falling factorial with respect to the rising factorial ... how do I develop that matrix? Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Tom -- That's a more interesting question. But maybe one could first do the falling factorials in terms of usual powers, and then after that to go from rising to falling (skipping the usual powers) would involve multiplying one of the matrices by the inverse of the other.

Comment: wow ... thanks for that. I will have to play around with that idea to see if I can develop the correct stirling number matrix.

Comment: @Tom Just added something on going from rising to falling. Note to go in the reverse order one can just use $N^{-1}$ which looks a lot like $N$ but two entries are of opposite sign.

Comment: Thanks again ... you sure are thorough, it has been most helpful. Are you using Tex, to be able to use these math formats? I am busy downloading it and then I hope to learn to use it.

Comment: @railsdancer The formats are built into the site, often one just encloses something inside $ signs, and you can get the idea by taking various answers and clicking on edit to see how the math notation got built. (Then clik cancel edit afterwards!)